# how to restore a mysql database from full database backup

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have all MySQL databases backup dump file (50 Databases) with in a server, and i want to restore a single database from this dump file.Is that possible? Any suggestions?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It mostly depends on the format of your backup. What does your backup look like?

Comment: Do you use `mysqldump` for the backup? Do you do one for each database?

Comment: Assuming you've used `mysqldump` with the option `--all-databases` then you can import a single database using `mysql -u root -p --one-database My_DB_NAME < all_databases_dump.sql`

Comment: @val0x00ff that is a somewhat dangerous operation for an inexperienced user to attempt.

Comment: @lgeorget its like full_backup.sql

Answer (score -1):

Yes
Just copy your full-backu.sql into C:\xampp\mysql\bin
then open cmd.exe (command prompet ) with administrator account
then run : 
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root -p --one-database destdbname < full-backu.sql

goodluck

Comment: This seems to be a windows solution.